# Import saved email into IMAP folder

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I accidentally deleted an email and then *mis-clicked* on it in the trash folder, deleting it permanently (Mail on *iOS*).   I managed to log onto another machine with an open IMAP client ([Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/)) and save the email to disk.
Is there a way to get it back into my *inbox*?

Answer (score 0):

Copy to folder was not working whilst the message was deleted on the server but still present in Thunderbird. However, opening the saved message from disk in Thunderbird allows the copy to folder action to complete (`File->Open->Saved Message` then `Message->Copy To`)